# Rails 'config.time_zone' doesn't apply to datetime data loaded into a text_field. Fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, datetime

When I use a datetime_select in my form, Rails will correctly adjust the timezone of the datetime data (as per my `config.time_zone` setting), and will render the properly-zoned time in the `edit` view of that same form.

But when I try to retrieve that same data into a text_field (for the same `edit` view of the same form), Rails doesn't seem to adjust for time zone.

/events/edit.html.erb (full file):

```
<h1>Edit This Event</h1>
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Update Event" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

/events/_fields.html.erb (relevant lines only:)

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label      :time_start, "Start Time" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field  :time_start, :class => "datetimefield" %>
</div>
```

**Example:** My zone's offset is -500.  I enter 8:00 as the start_time in the form, 13:00 UTC is written to the database, 8:00 is rendered on the `show` page (thanks to `config.time_zone` accounting for the offset), but when I try to edit that object, the form's text_field for the start_time is loaded with 13:00 (which, if submitted unaltered, becomes 18:00 when it's stored in the database).

This is problematic, because I'm trying to use jQuery UI's DatePicker (with a TimePicker add-on), which relies on the text_field (won't work with a `datetime_select`).

Is there a way to make Rails apply the `config.time_zone` offset to text fields?

***Running Rails 3.0.5, deploying to Heroku.***

*Apologies in advance for having asked a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336235/rails-app-config-time-zone-not-applying-when-populating-form-fields-for-edit-v) a few weeks ago.  The information there still applies, I just have a better understanding of the problem now, so I re-asked.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I said in the question, the main problem I had was getting ActiveRecord to apply the existing 'config.time_zone' setting to text_fields.

It turns out that there's a very simple and future-proof way to make that happen: just explicitly add a :value and pull the exact same data--no extra/new methods to call!  In my case, that meant:

```
<%= f.text_field  :time_start, :value => f.object.time_start, :class => "datetimefield" %>
```

This was an intermediary step to another potential solution I was going to try, and I was surprised to find that it worked all on its own (again, working with the 'config.time_zone' I'd already set in 'config/application.rb').

I've tested it, and it applies the proper DST offset when applicable as well (just as one would expect, since 'config.time_zone' is set).

Comment: Indeed, best solution even 4 years later.
In case you use simple form: 

`f.input :time_start, input_html: {value: f.object.time_start}`

Answer (score 1):

How about converting it with `TimeZone#utc_to_local`?

Check out the API docs, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html