# Timezone conversion not happening when displaying information on form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, timezone, utc

I've read a lot of posts concerning this issue, but none seems to tackle it clearly enough.

Basically I have a model `Receipt` with a datetime field `doc_date`

When I save the date, I save it in my local area (Lisbon, currently with DST : GMT +1). 
In DB I have Utc (gmt) date. That is, less one hour than the one I'm currently at.

So far, so good.

The problem is when I load my fields to a form.

```
<%= form_for(@receipt) do |f| %>
[...]
 <div class="field">
      Date Test </br>
      <%=  @receipt.doc_date %>
    </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :doc_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :doc_date %>
 </div>
[...]
<% end %>
```

If the date saved was let's Say "August 1, 2013, 00:00", the display date on the Doc date input field is "July 31, 2013, 23:00".

Date Test on the other end shows it right

```
Date Test
2013/08/01 00:00
```

In my application_controller I also have

```
before_filter :set_user_time_zone

  #Sets the user default time zone to the one configured in the db
  def set_user_time_zone

    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if user_signed_in?
  end
```

In my application.rb I have `config.time_zone = 'Lisbon'`

I'm running Rails 3.2.

If I run Receipt.where(id:18365).first.doc_date in the console, the date also returns 1 August 00:00, so the problem seems to be loading the form...

So this seems to be either related to Rails skipping Timezone conversion for form fields, or something related to the fact I have the jquery datepicker calendar for that field...

Any suggestions to show the correct local date time on the form field?

Comment: This question might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554075/rails-config-time-zone-doesnt-apply-to-datetime-data-loaded-into-a-text-field

Comment: Definitely so. Adding value: f.object.doc_date, did the trick. `<%= f.text_field :doc_date, value: f.object.doc_date %>`. Thanks !

Comment: @trh want to write that as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments:

Timezone for a field has a great answer : [Rails 'config.time_zone' doesn't apply to datetime data loaded into a text_field. Fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554075/rails-config-time-zone-doesnt-apply-to-datetime-data-loaded-into-a-text-field)

---

```
<%= f.text_field :doc_date, value: f.object.doc_date %>
```