# stop simple_form from converting datetime to utc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a datetime that gets rendered into a hidden form field using simple_form. The field is called next_event: The erb line looks like this:

```
  <%= f.input :next_event, as: :hidden, label: false %>
```

I want this string to be the datetime in the user's local time zone. If I set a breakpoint in the controller code, I can see that the variable is in the correct time zone (in this case, MDT):

```
:next_event => Wed, 28 May 2014 15:30:00 MDT -06:00,
```

However, when it gets rendered in HTML, the date time is converted to UTC:

```
<input class="hidden" id="foo_next_event" name="foo[next_event]" type="hidden" value="2014-05-28 21:30:00">
```

What can I do to get simple_form to stop converting to utc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554075/rails-config-time-zone-doesnt-apply-to-datetime-data-loaded-into-a-text-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually specify the value so that the TimeZone conversion doesn't take place:

```
<%= f.input :next_event, as: :hidden, label: false, input_html: { value: f.object.next_event.to_s } %>
```

Another option... may be to use the `*_before_type_cast` method for your attribute. So in the model define:

```
def next_event_before_type_cast
  self[:next_event].to_s
end
```

With this approach you should get the result you want without having to worry about formatting of the date in forms here (or elsewhere).