# How to display local time on form when column has type datetime is saved in database in UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a column called **`test_date`**, type `datetime` in General Exam table. I built a form to create and update GeneralExam, on form, I allow User choose a date and time throught [`jQuery UI Datepicker`](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

After user choose date and time, it will displayed in textfield, like:

`25-11-2012 16:30`

It is my current time. When I run in console, I see the `test_date` was saved in database is:

`2012-11-25 09:30:00`

And when I get object GeneralExam, and get `test_date` value, it is:

```
g = GeneralExam.last
g.test_date
=> Sun, 25 Nov 2012 16:30:00 ICT +07:00
```

I think `test_date` is converted, because I set up in `application.rb` is:

```
config.time_zone = 'Hanoi'
```

But when I update a General Exam on form, it still display the time was saved in database, not my local timezone, it means it display:

`2012-11-25 09:30:00`

But I want it is like what I chose on form:

`25-11-2012 16:30:00`

How can I set up for display datetime column in local time?

And I think the order of date was reversed, when I choose date, it is `25-11-2012`, but when it displayed it was `2012-11-25`, Why it reversed the order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After few hours I search on google and stackoverflow, I think I found what I want. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336235/rails-app-config-time-zone-not-applying-when-populating-form-fields-for-edit/6585693#6585693) and find some information about [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime) method. This is what information I need to solve my problem.

First, How to display datetime was saved in UTC as local time when display it:

```
Value was saved:                             2012-11-25 09:30:00

Value I want display on form (ICT +7:00):    25-11-2012 16:30:00
```

To display value I want, I used this on form (I used simple_form):

```
<%= f.input :test_date, as: :string, label: false, input_html: { id: "datetime_picker", value: f.object.test_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M") } %>
```

I have got value in database and format it by:

```
value: f.object.test_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M") } %>
```

And when I want display `test_date` in table data, I also used `strftime("%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M")` to display datetime format as I want.

Comment: `value: f.object.test_date.localtime` is shorter

Answer (score 0):

The proper setting is related with your Rails config , but also with your DB config . There is a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised?view=asciicast) , explaining  how to avoid most of the gotchas . For consistency all the dates and times are saved in the database in UTC . The conversion is made by Rails config , depending on your config.time_zone . In this case you should try :

```
Time.zone.now
```

which takes in account the configuration in Rails and  is different from:

```
Time.now
```

Comment: I don't want to get the current time, but I want display the time saved in database in local. After going around, I found solution, I will post it as answer :)